# Returning response vs echoing - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel, when I send a response back for a user's request, it performs the same thing if I just echoed or printed out the response data, instead of actually returning the response. My question is, is it really necessary to send a response when You can just echo out the response data?

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning a response is always better than echoing them. If you echo a response in a framework, say Laravel, you won't get much privileges with it. For example, in complex applications, sometimes you would need an *after middleware* which adds things to your response before sending them to the client. If you just echo them, you won't get much to do with it.

Returning a response also allows you to change data exchange format(from XML to JSON) with the help of say a middleware, but if you echo them, you would have to change the echo in each and every file.

Sometimes, you would also need to put a `die` after `echo` if you want to halt the further framework execution immediately, which is a bad practice. It is always good to have a graceful execution of code inside a framework from start to end.

In addition to the above, [`Response`](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Http/Response.html) class provides much more features than a simple echo.